# Android ScrollView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

i want to have like this design.header when listview and image bellow in this listview.i wrote xml code.also i used scrollview but my listview's height des not change when i adaptered my array.i can show only first item in listview.
in my option problem is xml file
this is a source xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#ff0000" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/geocell" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </ListView>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/popapshow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/geocell" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i guess scrollview can have only one child still i am not so sure about the question!please ellaborate

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this layout... Most notably you have a `ListView` with `wrap_content` as height and a `ListView` inside another `ScrollView`. Overall this layout is a lot more complex than it has to be. I see so many redundant views that don't really do anything...

Comment: if you put ListView ScrollView then your ListView Scroll is not working so you can't use Scrollable view inside ScrollView.

Comment: what is a solution in your option ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `LinearLayout` from the root and add `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Actually your question is not too clear to understand your requirements,can u please specify more clearly ?

Comment: i try to understn you.i have one image and lisview bellow in this image and alsow i have one image  whitch is also bellow in listview.when i adaptered my arralist in listview  i can show only thist item